# vue-svg-loader removes some <g> tags while loading SVGs

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js, external, loader

I am loading an external svg into my Vue application as a Vue Component using the **vue-svg-loader**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-loader?activeTab=readme.
I modified the loader configuration to make sure the IDs don't get dropped:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: 'vue-svg-loader', // `vue-svg` for webpack 1.x
  options: {
    // optional [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) options
    svgo: {
      plugins: [
        {removeDoctype: true},
        {removeComments: true},
        {cleanupIDs: false}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The svg I am trying to load looks something like this:

```
<svg class="external-svg">
   <g class="group-1">
      <path id="a"></path>
      <path id="b"></path>
      <path id="c"></path>
   </g>
   <g class="group-2">
      <path id="d"></path>
   </g>
   <g class="group-3">
      <path id="e"></path>
      <path id="f"></path>
      <path id="g"></path>
   </g>
   <g class="group-4">
      <path id="h"></path>
   </g>
   <g class="group-5">
   </g>
</svg>
```

Using the loader, the svg loads successfully, but some of the  tags get dropped. The resulting  looks as follows:

```
<svg class="external-svg">
   <g class="group-1">
      <path id="a"></path>
      <path id="b"></path>
      <path id="c"></path>
   </g>
   <path id="d"></path>
   <g class="group-3">
      <path id="e"></path>
      <path id="f"></path>
      <path id="g"></path>
   </g>
   <path id="h"></path>
</svg>
```

"group-2", "group-4" and "group-5" get dropped, but the paths inside are intact.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or know a good solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the loader is trying to optimize by removing what it sees as unnecessary group tags (i.e. groups with just a single child element). Of course, that does remove the class, and it could also effect styles that were targeted at groups. You might want to file an issue with the maintainer

Comment: Thanks @StephenThomas! I did file an issue and got a quick response too. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to this issue and for anyone else who might be having similar problems, here is the solution:
Change the loader configuration to the following:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: 'vue-svg-loader', // `vue-svg` for webpack 1.x
  options: {
    svgo: {
      plugins: [
        {removeDoctype: true},
        {removeComments: true},
        {cleanupIDs: false},
        {collapseGroups: false},
        {removeEmptyContainers: false}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Other configurations for the loader are available here: https://github.com/svg/svgo

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who uses vue cli:

```
*vue.config.js*


module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule
      .use('babel-loader')
      .loader('babel-loader')
      .end()
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader')
      .options({
        svgo: {
          plugins: [
            { cleanupIDs: false },
            { collapseGroups: false },
            { removeEmptyContainers: false },
          ],
        },
      });
  },
};
```

you are probably searching for this in order to get rid of cleaning up ids or collapsing groups